# How do you draw simple lattice diagrams with MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, images, reference-request

How do I make a lattice diagram, for example a tower of field extensions, on this website using MathJax?

[image]

I'll also accept a redirect to a helpful page. [Here's a link to the original question I asked on TexSE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219005/52612).

Comment: @Arkamis So it seems there's not an easy way. Disheartening, but helpful anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately so. The easiest way might be to become familiar with some of the LaTeX commutative diagramming tools and use a service such as [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) to code up the image. From there, it's easy enough to embed the image in a question.

Comment: For bonus points, you could make public the tex document and provide a link so others could edit.

Comment: @Arkamis Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: @Arkamis Bonus points counter-offer: Do you know of any other relevant tags to add? I couldn't find any syntax-related ones.

Comment: Most questions pertaining to Mathjax usage are generally considered to belong on Meta, actually.

Comment: @Arkamis Ah, that's good to know. Is there a way I can migrate it (so the comments and answers still appear)?

Comment: You can flag and just comment that it should be migrated. But since this question has an accepted answer, I'd just let it be. Eventually someone else will search for what you're asking on main, and they might come across this question.

Comment: This [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122775/four-node-commutative-diagram-in-latex) has an example with TikZ and TikZ-cd on making a lattice type diagrams.

Comment: The technical term is [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).

Comment: Related: [How to draw a commutative diagram?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram)

Comment: For what it's worth, MathJax was never really meant for this sort of thing. (Not as of today, at least, though perhaps it will be in the future.) It's meant as a way to render simple formulas, not as a complete in-browser implementation of (La)TeX; in fact the only reason MathJax has anything to do with TeX is that the LaTeX/AMSTeX syntax for math is the one that most professionals are familiar with.

Comment: FWIW, the reason why MathJax currently does not easily draw more advanced diagrams, in particular diagonal arrows, is that our underlying format is MathML which does not easily lend itself to that. In the long run, we hope to add SVG-based extensions as part of core MathJax. E.g. the third party xyjax extension provides much of xypic (using SVG).

Comment: It seems that many users who need similar diagrams ([field extensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=field+extension+site:math.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch)
or [Galois theory](https://www.google.com/search?q=galois+site:math.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch) or
[subgroups](https://www.google.com/search?q=subgroups+site:math.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch) or
[Hasse diagrams in general](https://www.google.com/search?q=hasse+site:math.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch)) include them in images.

Comment: One possibility would be to ask also in comments to some of those posts what software the particular poster used, but I am not sure whether you will learn something which is not already covered in some of the several meta posts on this or closely related topics).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's probably not the best solution, but you could use a matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
 && \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},i) & \\
&\huge\diagup & \huge| & \huge\diagdown \\
\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}) & & \Bbb Q(i\sqrt{2})&  & \Bbb Q(i)\\
&\huge\diagdown & \huge| & \huge\diagup \\
&&\Bbb Q
\end{matrix}$$

```
\begin{matrix}
  && \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},i) & \\
  &\huge\diagup & \huge| & \huge\diagdown \\
  \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}) & & \Bbb Q(i\sqrt{2})&  & \Bbb Q(i)\\
  &\huge\diagdown & \huge| & \huge\diagup \\
  &&\Bbb Q
\end{matrix}
```

Comment: or $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$$$$\Bigg / \hspace{.75cm}\Bigg \vert \hspace{.75cm}\Bigg \backslash $$$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\hspace{1.5cm}\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})\hspace{1.5cm}\mathbb{Q}(i)$$$$\Bigg \backslash \hspace{.75cm} \Bigg \vert \hspace{.75cm}\Bigg /$$$$\mathbb{Q}$$

Answer (score 1):

I've researched a few basic commutative diagramming tools and eventually settled with *TikZ*. To be able to "use" this on MathSE you have to create a TeX document and upload the image.